# how to populate text field once a comboBox change in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I do have to tables that are connected with a relationship. I want to display a Name from the other table once the the combo box change. For example, I have table1 where it has table2ForeignKey and I want to populate a text field in a form using the the table2Name I create a query but I dont know to to connected with the combo Box cause I want the Id of the combobox to be pass to the query then the query to validate the combo box Id and return the value to get a clear Id the query I built:

```
SELECT Colleges.College_Name
FROM Users INNER JOIN Colleges ON Users.college_id = Colleges.college_id
WHERE ((([Combo37])=[Users].[User_Id]));
```

SO I have table users and in the users there is field of the college ID and I want to get the college name using its foreign key by validating the join method and the query by its self it works with no issue but I am not sure how to let the query read the user idea input from the combobox cause every time I open the query it read(combo37) as just a variable(knowing that combo37 is the name of the combobox) and it ask me to input the combo37 manually so my question is how to pass a value from a combobox to a query and how to let the textfield to be populated using this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't know what `[Combo37]` is that's why when you open the query it askf for a value.

You need to tell the query where/what the `[combo37]` is. Try something like

```
SELECT Colleges.College_Name
FROM Users INNER JOIN Colleges ON Users.college_id = Colleges.college_id
WHERE (
 [Users].[User_Id] = Forms!formName![combo37]
);
```

so the query knows which form look for to find the combo37 object.
Make sure the form is open before you run this query.